# `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'` when convert float list to complex list

Tags: python, numpy, cmath

Python script to convert float list to complex list as below:

```
data=[0.1455056963719547,3.068672071910097e-07,-1.50649354101907e-10,-0.07398991280122003]
complex_data=data[1::2]*1j
complex_data+=data[0::2]
```

give me `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'`

Even,

```
print(1j*[0.1455056963719547,3.068672071910097e-07,-1.50649354101907e-10,-0.07398991280122003])
print(1j*[0.1455056963719547,3.06867207191009707,1.5064935410190710,0.07398991280122003])
```

has same error.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are using is valid for `numpy.ndarray` but has a different meaning for `list`.

```
assert([1] * 4 == [1, 1, 1, 1])
>>>True
```

In essence if you multiply a list `a` by an integer `n`, it's producing a list made of `n` times the elements of `a`.

If you want to multiply all the elements of a list by a scalar, you can use a comprehension:

```
data = [0.1455056963719547,3.068672071910097e-07,-1.50649354101907e-10,-0.07398991280122003]
complex_data = [el * 1j for el in data[1::2]]
complex_data = [re + im for re, im in zip(data[0::2], complex_data)]
```

or more directly:

```
 complex_data = [re + im * 1j for re, im in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])]
```

If your list is large, there is a trick to avoid creating copies:

```
data = [re + im * 1j for re, im in zip(*[iter(data)] * 2)]
```

Or more readable:

```
it = iter(data)
data = [re + im * 1j for re, im in zip(it, it)]
```

You may want to use `numpy` for large datasets. An efficient way to load your data would be for example:

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

data_file = Path('./data.txt')
data = np.fromfile(data_file, sep='\n')

data = data.astype(float).view(complex)
```

which **doesn't copy the data** at all and turns it effortlessly into complex numbers.

Comment: Can I replace `data` in place `data = [re + im * 1j for re, im in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])]`?`data` is 4GB size.

Comment: Updated for large lists. 4GB was worth mentioning!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a solution rather than the cause of the problem, I simply suggest you to use `numpy` such as what follows:

```py
import numpy as np
data=[0.1455056963719547,3.068672071910097e-07,-1.50649354101907e-10,-0.07398991280122003]
data = np.array(data)
complex_data=data[1::2]*1j
complex_data+=data[0::2]
```